# What exactly is considered a breaking change to a PureScript library?

Tags: semantic-versioning, purescript

The Rust community has a [fairly detailed description](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1105-api-evolution.md) of their interpretation of Semantic Versioning.

The PureScript community has [this](https://github.com/purescript/purescript/wiki/Dependency-Management-Discussion), which includes:

> We should write a semver tutorial for beginners, specifically its use in PureScript and the way we rely on ~-versions.

The odd thing is that looking at an assortment of 65 randomish purescript libraries, they all use ^-versions rather than ~-versions, but I have been unable to find any newer documentation and we recently had our build broken due to a mismatch in expectations.

Does the PureScript community have a reasonably consistent interpretation of semver, specifically regarding what is or isn't considered a breaking change? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 5):

We don't have an exhaustive list anywhere, no. Now's as good a time as any to start one!

- Taking advantage of features that require a newer compiler than when the current version was released.
- Adding a dependency.
- Removing a dependency.
- Bumping a dependency's major version.
- Deleting or renaming a module.
- Removing a member (that means anything - type, value, class, kind, operator) from a module (either by hiding the export or deleting it).
- Changing a type signature of an existing function or value in a way that means it won't unify with the previous version (so it is allowable to make types more general, but not less so).
- Adding, removing, or altering the kind of type variables for a type.
- Adding, removing, or altering data constructors for a type (unless the type does not export its constructors).
- Adding or removing members of a type class declaration.
- Changing the expected type parameters of a class.
- Adding or altering functional dependencies of a class.
- Changing the laws of a class.
- Removing instances of a class.

Pretty much anything other than adding new members (or re-exports) to a module is considered a breaking change!

Occasionally we've made changes that are technically breaking (due to type signature changes), but done so to fix something that was completely unusable without the fix. In those cases they've gone out as patch bumps, but those cases are very rare. They tend only to occur when the FFI is involved.

Re: `~` vs `^`... I think at the time the linked page was made there wasn't the option to use `^` in Bower (or it didn't default to that at least). `^` is the preferred/recommended range to use for libraries now.